# Solving for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need assistance in solving this differential equation related to an electronics course: $$V= R\frac{dQ}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C}$$

The solution is supposed to be $$Q = CV \left(1-e^\frac{-t}{RC} \right)$$ This is my work:

$$\int \frac{dt}{RC} = \int \frac{dQ}{CV-Q}$$

$$CVe^\frac{t}{RC} = e^{\ln|CV-Q|}$$

$$CV \left(1-e^{\frac{t}{RC}}\right)= Q$$

Comment: But what is the question ?

Comment: My solution has a positive exponent when the textbook provides a negative exponent. Look closely.

Comment: The $\ln$ in your second last line should have a minus sign.  Check by differentiation.

Comment: I am sorry : I missed the sign difference (I am almost blind !). David gave you the answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: ah the capacitor charge equation?